# I'm getting 400 (Bad Request) . I am trying to POST data to my database. POST request .I don't know if its the server issue. But it takes the values

Tags: reactjs, post, fetch, nsfetchrequest

I want to send data to my database, the names and the input types are true, but I don't understand the issues. I got 400 (Bad Request).I don't see the problem, my schema is all strings, the inputs are string type too. It takes the values correctly but doesn't Post them.
.it gives me this message when i asked to console.log(result) - {message: 'Please fullfil all fields!'}

```
   import "./CreateRecipe.css";
import { Link, NavLink, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import React, { useLayoutEffect, useState } from 'react';
import * as recipeService from "../../../services/recipeService";

const CreateRecipe = () => {

    useLayoutEffect(() => {
        window.scrollTo(0, 0)
    });

    const scrollToTop = () => {
        window.scrollTo(0, 0)
    }

    const navigate = useNavigate();

    const onCreateRecipe = (e) => {

        e.preventDefault();

        let recipeData = new FormData(e.currentTarget);

        let name = recipeData.get('name');
        let time = recipeData.get('time');
        let imageUrl = recipeData.get('imageUrl');
        let ingredients = recipeData.get('ingredients');
        let instructions = recipeData.get('instructions');

        recipeService.create({
            name,
            time,
            imageUrl,
            ingredients,
            instructions,
        })
        .then(result => {
            navigate('/recipes');
        })
    }

    return (
        <div className = "maind">
            <section className="sec3">
        <div>
           <h1>Add Your Recipe</h1>
           <form id="createform" onSubmit={onCreateRecipe} method="POST">
           <fieldset>
            <legend>Fill the form</legend>
            <label name="namel">Name</label>
            <input type="text" name = "name" id="name" placeholder="...."/>
            <label name="timel">Time</label>
            <input type="text" name = "time" id="time" placeholder="...."/>
            <label name="url">Url</label>
            <input type="text" name = "imageUrl" id="imageUrl" placeholder="...."/>
            <label name="ingredl">Ingredients</label>
            <textarea  name = "ingredients" id="ingredients" placeholder="...."/>
            <label name="instl">Instructions</label>
            <textarea  name = "instructions" id="instructions" placeholder="...."/>
            <button class="btnad" type="submit">Add</button>
            </fieldset>
           </form>
        </div>
    
    </section>
        <section className="sec5navl">
        <ul>
            <li><Link smooth= "true" to="/"><i className="fas fa-solid fa-book-bookmark"></i></Link>Home</li>
            <li><Link smooth= "true" to="/recipes"><i className="fas fa-thin fa-bowl-rice"></i></Link>Recipes</li>
            <li><Link smooth= "true" to="/personal-list"><i className="fas fa-solid fa-list-ul"></i></Link>Your Recipes</li>
            <li><Link smooth= "true" to="/favourites"><i className="fa-solid fa-heart"></i></Link>Favourites</li>
            <li><Link smooth= "true" to="/create-recipe"><i className="fas fa-solid fa-plus"></i></Link>Add Recipe</li>
            <li><Link smooth= "true" to="/user-profile"><i className="fas fa-solid fa-user"></i></Link>Your Profile</li>
            <li><Link smooth= "true" onClick={scrollToTop} to="/create-recipe"><i class="fas fa-solid fa-arrow-up"></i></Link>Up</li>
        </ul>
        </section>
        </div>
    );
}

export default CreateRecipe;
```

That's my the Create function from recipe Service.I don't understand the parsing JSON, the POST methods, I just copied it and in the video of the programmer worked it's exactly the same....

```
   export const create = (recipeData) => {
    let response = fetch(`${baseUrl}/recipes`, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'content-type': 'application-json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(recipeData)
    });
    
    let result = response.json();

    return result;
    
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You are expecting `recipeService.create()` to return a promise, but it isn't asynchronous... try this:

```js
export const create = async (recipeData) => {
  const response = await fetch(`${baseUrl}/recipes`, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(recipeData)
  });
    
  return response.json();
    
};
```

Also: you may change all your let declarations for a const instead, as your variables are never reassigned.
https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/prefer-const

Comment: Thank you. I tried your version it stills gives me the error. It navigates to the page it goes trough the logic but still doesn't take the data i don't get it....it gives me this message when i asked to console.log(result) - {message: 'Please fullfil all fields!'}

Comment: try to fix your header property: `'content-type': 'application/json'` (slash, not dash)

Comment: no sorry it gave me this error TypeError: Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window': Invalid name

Comment: oh sorry, also the capital C in Content-type:
`'Content-Type': 'application/json'`